# Need a script to list webparts on each .aspx page in wss3.0 (using stsadm command)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, wss-3.0, stsadm

Need a script to list webparts used in a web application on each .aspx page for wss3.0 using stsadm command. The list should show webparts per page, their names and Id's. Thanks

I used VB Script from this [LINK](http://chanakyajayabalan.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/list-all-sharepoint-site-collections-and-sub-sites-recursively/) and could only list the websites and then had to manually open each websites and do ?contents=1 for each page and write down webparts, which is a painful job when it comes to web application which has number of websites.

Comment: Is writing/executing a console application an option?

Comment: Yes I have managed to install PS console and then I was able to pull the records using PS commands. thx :)